# Linking to the itunes store

Tags: iphone, itunes

I would like to add buttons which allow the user to buy music on itunes.

When the button is selected itunes opens to the specific track or album and when the user is done it returns to the app? Can this be done inside the app or will it open itunes separately?

How does one do this in the code? Built in methods?

I am also wondering how it works when users are from different regions and have Itunes accounts in those areas. How are the different stores opened? Or does itunes handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make the App Store app return back to your app "when the user is done" -- not only is the functionality not there, that action is ill-defined.

With iOS 4.x multitasking, however, users can double-tap the home bottom to bring up the multitasking pane, which allows them so "fast switch" back to your app after they're "done".

Comment: Thanks. but how are the links setup to open in itunes?

Comment: @alJaree, you might be interested in Apple's 'iTunes link maker': http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker

Comment: Thanks that solved it. different outcomes on device and simulator. :)